# Custom indent formatting of Java method declarations in Eclipse..?

Tags: java, eclipse

When typing or copy/pasting method declarations, and then using AutoFormat (ctrl+i), I end up with something like this:

```
public String method1(){}
public int method2(){}
public void method3(){}
```

Is there a way for auto-format to do it like this instead, so the method names are all indented to the same position?

```
public String  method1(){}
public int     method2(){}
public void    method3(){}
```

I understand Eclipse has a section in Preferences to control the auto-formating, but I do not fully understand how to use it.

Thanks.

Comment: Its not a good practice to keep your code in the 2nd mentioned format. You shouldn't try to align anything. May be this will help... https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.6.3-horizontal-alignment

Comment: before you judge my response take 2 minutes to open the link and read the tip mentioned in yellow box... once done you can make your decision.. Also they have put considerable effort and experience in to creating these things, don't disregard them so quickly.